# Appending a character to field records based on a repeated value from the second field

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have this input

```
array='2       0.00000         -1.45191
6       0.81778         -0.63413
10      0.85020         -0.60170
8       1.40260         -0.04931
22      3.25781         1.80590
20      4.32051         2.86860
6       0.00000         -0.93906
18      0.07618         -0.86288
8       0.36922         -0.56984
12      0.71195         -0.22711
16      0.88517         -0.05389'
```

I am trying to replicate the same array but as shown below,

```
2       0.00000         -1.45191
6       0.81778         -0.63413
10      0.85020         -0.60170
8       1.40260         -0.04931
22      3.25781         1.80590
20      4.32051         2.86860
6-      0.00000         -0.93906
18-     0.07618         -0.86288
8-      0.36922         -0.56984
12-     0.71195         -0.22711
16-     0.88517         -0.05389
```

The difference is, suffixing the second part of the first field `$1` using the second `0.00000` value of the second field `$2` as an indicator.
I would be pleased if that's possible using the `awk` command.

Comment: What are the delimiters in your `array`? Do you care about preserving the alignment?

Comment: Can you please write math formula of calculation of the values in result matrix?

Comment: And is it quotation mark on the last row an error or it should be there?

Comment: @steeldriver I'm not sure what you meant by "delimiters" and I used it to mean an indicator; that is, where the action should start to take effect. And yes, the alignment is important, as it looks in the question, I mean in a matrix form.

Comment: @RomeoNinov What did you mean by a math formula? I don't see it as relevant and I didn't use it to produce my question. I edited my question about the quotation mark; it was a mistake.

Comment: How is this minus appear in first column?

Comment: @RomeoNinov It is a character used to distinguish the bottom part from the previous one.

Comment: Please define the login where to add minus and where not

Comment: I don't understand "the login" statement, could you explain your comment?
From the question, it is clear where the minus sign should be made.

Comment: EnthusiastiC @RomeoNinov means `logic`, not `login`. Reading your question we see some first fields suddenly get `-`s attached and others don't, with no obvious reason for that. It's not clear what `suffixing the second part of the first field $1 using the second 0.00000 value of the second field $2 as an indicator` might mean.

Comment: In your previous question it caused problems with some answers that your real input was tab-separated but you didn't tell us so if the input in your new question is tab separated - please do [edit] your question tell us as once again you're getting answers assuming they're separated by blanks.

Comment: Please stop using the name `array` for scalar variables as it makes your questions more confusing than they have to be.

Comment: @EdMorton `suffixing the second part...` I mean appending the minus `-` character to the bottom part of that field. I didn't understand what does it supposed to mean by "first fields ". There is only one field that is `$1` which is modified.

Comment: About the tabs and spaces being used as separators, I don't want to change them because answers have already been given and if I edit my questions their answers seem to be partly wrong. At least that is how I see things to be, if otherwise, I will edit them.

Comment: Yes, we know you want to append `-`, it's just not clear in your question under what conditions to do so. Yes, we know you want to change the `$1`s - those are the first fields in your input. I'm not suggesting you change anything about the spaces, just state what they are - if they're tabs state that, if they're blanks then state that.

Comment: What should happen if a 3rd `0.00000` in $2 occurs - should lines afterwards continue to get `-`s appended to the first field or not? Different answers are making different assumptions about that. Please [edit] your question to state whatever your requirement is for that (and it'd be good to include that case in your sample input/output).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your example, what you *appear* to want to do is keep a count of occurrences of the string `0.00000` (or possibly the numerical value `0`) in the second column, and append `-` to the value of the first column when the count reaches 2:

```
printf '%s\n' "$array" | awk '$2 == "0.00000" {++ind} ind == 2 {$1 = $1"-"} 1'
```

However this will replace the column separators with the default (single space) output separator in records that satisfy the condition. **If** your input separators are sequences of space characters, then one way to preserve the alignment would be to replace the first space character with `-`:

```
$ printf '%s\n' "$array" | awk '$2 == "0.00000" {++ind} ind == 2 {sub(/ /,"-")} 1'
2       0.00000         -1.45191
6       0.81778         -0.63413
10      0.85020         -0.60170
8       1.40260         -0.04931
22      3.25781         1.80590
20      4.32051         2.86860
6-      0.00000         -0.93906
18-     0.07618         -0.86288
8-      0.36922         -0.56984
12-     0.71195         -0.22711
16-     0.88517         -0.05389
```

Comment: Absolutely correct answer. However, I didn't understand the `{sub(/ /,"-")}` command why does it replace the first column and doesn't affect the second and the third fields?

Comment: @EnthusiastiC the `sub(regex, sub, string)` function only replaces the first matching occurrence of `regex`. If `string` is omitted, it operates on `$0` (and by **not** operating on `$1` we avoid re-writing `$0` with the default `FS`). See for example [AWK - String Functions](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/awk/awk_string_functions.htm)

Answer (score 1):

We can use `awk` to solve it:

```bsh
printf '%s\n' "$array" |
awk -F '\t' 'BEGIN{OFS=FS}
($2 ~ /^0\.0+$/ && ++k==2),0 {
  $1 = $1 "-"
}1' -
```

- We use the range operator `,`
- The range operator , initially is false. And when the left operand evaluates to true, the range becomes true and stays true until the right operand evaluates to true.
- The left operand is `$2 ~ /^0\.0+$/ && ++k==2`
- So it will evaluate true when the second column is floating point zero AND this is happening for the second time.
- After that the range operator remains true until the right evaluates true, which in our case is 0 so will never happen.
- IOW, the range is true starting the line where second column was zero till eof.
- Action during range is first field is suffixed by a dash.
- the lone **1** shall print to STDOUT the reconstituted $0 by concatenating the fiels using TABs (OFS) since we touched one of the fields.

---

---

Using `GNU sed` in extended regex mode (`-E`) to simplify the writing of regexes:

```bsh
printf '%s\n' "$array" |
sed -E '
  0,/^[^\t]+\t+0\.0+(\t|$)/b
  //,$s/\t/-&/
' -
```

---

- The regex `/^[^\t]+\t+0\.0+(\t|$)/` selects line with the second field zero.
- The first range , selects lines from line number zero to the first occurrence of a zero in second column. All these lines are passed unmodified to STDOUT
- The next time, meaning the second time , a zero in second column is seen and until the eof, in that range , we change the first space character to a dash. This presupposes their are no leading spaces in the lines.
- Any other lines , not falling in these two ranges , are passed unmodified to STDOUT.
- The zeroth line number is a GNU sed extension to deal with cases where the regex matches the very first line  , as is your case.

---

Output:

```
2   0.00000 -1.45191
6   0.81778 -0.63413
10  0.85020 -0.60170
8   1.40260 -0.04931
22  3.25781 1.80590
20  4.32051 2.86860
6-  0.00000 -0.93906
18- 0.07618 -0.86288
8-  0.36922 -0.56984
12- 0.71195 -0.22711
16- 0.88517 -0.05389
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your previous question I suspect you have tab-separated input so try this:

```
$ printf '%s\n' "$array" | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} ($2==0) && c++{s="-"} {$1=$1 s} 1'
2       0.00000 -1.45191
6       0.81778 -0.63413
10      0.85020 -0.60170
8       1.40260 -0.04931
22      3.25781 1.80590
20      4.32051 2.86860
6-      0.00000 -0.93906
18-     0.07618 -0.86288
8-      0.36922 -0.56984
12-     0.71195 -0.22711
16-     0.88517 -0.05389
```

The above also assumes that if a 3rd or subsequent `0` appeared in column 2 you'd still want to append `-`s in column 1.

Comment: Could you tell what does this `&& c++{s="-"}` do?
I mean I know it checks for the second occurrence of the value `0` but what if someone wants to set it at the third occurrence?
And the variable `s` is it created as a field?

Comment: @EnthusiastiC Regarding `I edited the above answer...` - no, you may have edited some other answer but not the one above your comment.

Comment: The first time `c++` is hit, i.e. the first time `$2==0` is true, `c` is zero and so the condition it represents is false and so `{s="-"}` will not be hit and `s` remains as null but because of the `++` c will also be incremented after being tested, though, and so the 2nd and subsequent times that `$2==0` is true `c` will be non-zero (a true condition) and so `{s="-"}` will be hit and `s` will be set to `-`.  No, `s` isn't a field, it's just a variable whose contents get concatenated onto the end of every `$1`,